# Get latest/newest file based on file pattern in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, solaris

I am writing a Shell script in Bash, Solaris.

I am trying to get the latest file that match a particular file pattern and SCP it over.

I have been reading, and most implementations are based on ls commands, which does not work well with funny characters. I'm looking for alternatives that can work with what I have wrote so far.

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    for GMSFILE in $srcpath/KMS_MSEA_StatusAllocation_A*Y*.gms
    do
        if [ -e "$GMSFILE " ]
        then
            #GMS File Exist
            TXTFILE=${GMSFILE %%.*}.txt
            # Find same file name with txt extension now
            if [ -f "$TXTFILE" ]
            then
                echo $TXTFILE
                #scp -P 22 $GMSFILE $id@$ip:$destpath  #>> $log 2>&1
                break 2
            fi
        else
            sleep 5
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: is `stat` available on solaris systems? `stat --format %Y` would e.g. give the last modification time in epoch seconds - allowing for a quick integer-based comparison.

Comment: `ls -t [pattern] | head -n 1` will display the newest file that fits the pattern (assuming they're all in one directory).  What "funny characters" are causing problems?  Please provide an example of what you've tried to find the latest file - the script you posted has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `date` command with the `-r` option to display the last time a file was modified.  once you have the list of files you can use `date -r $TXTFILE +%s` to get the Unix date stamp of the last time the file was modified.  Once you know which value in the list is the most recent you can select to copy that item from the list.